# SQL Procedure Errors

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

i am learning mysql and have moved onto procedures. I have created a procedure and i am trying to run it. But when I run the procedure i am faced with lots of errors, the error point to lines that have no errors that I can see, can anyone help me out?

This is the procedure I have created

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE AD_AGENCY_INFO(
  v_ad_id IN ad_agency.AGENCY_ID%TYPE,
  v_cert IN ad_agency.NO_OF_AD_RUNS%TYPE,
  v_price IN ad_agency.CREDIT_WORTHY%TYPE,
  v_agency_id IN ad_agency.AGENCY_ID%TYPE
  ) AS
BEGIN

 UPDATE AD SET AD_ID = v_ad_id, CERTIFICTAION = v_cert, PRICE = v_price where agency_id = v_agency_id;
  INSERT INTO AD_SLOT (AD_ID) VALUES (v_ad_id);

 EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
rollback;

END AD_AGENCY_INFO;
```

This is how I am calling the procedure

```
   DECLARE
V_AGENCY_ID NUMBER:=&Enter_Agency_ID;
V_NO_OF_RUNS NUMBER:=&Enter_No_of_Runs;
V_CREDIT_WORTHY CHAR(3):=&Enter_Credit_Worthy;
V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS NUMBER:=&Enter_Available_Slots;
V_STATUS CHAR(1):=&Enter_Status;
  BEGIN
   V_AGENCY_ID := NULL;
V_NO_OF_RUNS := NULL;
V_CREDIT_WORTHY := NULL;
V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS := NULL;
V_STATUS := NULL;

AD_AGENCY_INFO(
  V_AGENCY_ID => V_AGENCY_ID,
  V_NO_OF_RUNS => V_NO_OF_RUNS,
  V_CREDIT_WORTHY => V_CREDIT_WORTHY,
  V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS => V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS,
  V_STATUS => V_STATUS
);
  END;
```

And this is the error log I get after running the procedure

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 28:
PLS-00201: identifier 'N' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 19:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 21:
PLS-00201: identifier 'Y' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 12:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 12, column 3:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 12, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 17, column 24:    
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 14, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: You are running Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: Sorry I am still learning all this, can you help me with the problems?

Comment: I can't -  I don't have enough experience with Oracle SPs, and its error messages are notoriously cryptic. I retagged the question though, so more Oracle-minded people will find it.

Comment: cool thanks for that, ill be more careful next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script that you're using to call the procedure, you're using substitution variables. They are replaced by their value before the script is interpreted. This means that a line like `V_CREDIT_WORTHY CHAR(3):=&Enter_Credit_Worthy;` with the value "no" will be translated into `V_CREDIT_WORTHY CHAR(3):=no;` You'll notice that "no" is unquoted there. In order to use substitution variables to pass a string to a PL/SQL script, you need to enclose the bind variable in quotes: `V_CREDIT_WORTHY CHAR(3):='&Enter_Credit_Worthy';`.

An alternative would be to use bind variables. They are interpreted as a part of the script and can therefore be treated as normal variable. To do this, you would simply need to replace the ampersands with colons. The line I referenced above would become `V_CREDIT_WORTHY CHAR(3):=:Enter_Credit_Worthy;`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made the changes you suggested and it eliminated alot of the errors but I still have this error 'Error report -
ORA-06550: line 14, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AD_AGENCY_INFO'
ORA-06550: line 14, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:'

Comment: That error seems pretty straight-forward: Oracle doesn't think the type of the variables declared in your script match your procedure declaration. Since your procedure use `%TYPE` we would need the table definition to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I edited the code but I am getting an error on line 14 bu the code stops on line 12

Comment: fixed the last error had the procedure mixed up with another one